# run for loop with bash command in fish shell

Tags: bash, shell-script, fish

I'm trying to run a simple command on my fish shell, but I am not able to execute. It just keeps adding lines for me to add additional data to, not sure on how to execute accordingly.

```
$ for acc in `cat uniprot_ids.txt` ; do curl -s "https://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/$acc.fasta" ; done > uniprot_seqs.fasta
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fish is not bash compatible, but uses its own scripting language.

In this case the only differences are

1. it doesn't support backticks (```), instead it uses parentheses.
2. for-loops don't use do/done, instead they just end in "end"

`for acc in (cat uniprot_ids.txt); curl -s "https://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/$acc.fasta" ; end > uniprot_seqs.fasta`

Also command substitutions only split on newlines, not newlines/spaces/tabs, but I'm betting this has entries on lines anyway. If not, you need to use `string split`.

Comment: hey thanks! :) I will also try this out and take into consideration but doing as a I mentioned below also worked :D

Comment: I mean, yeah, it _works_. But it's a bit of a cop-out, quoting can be annoying and actually learning the shell you're using seems like it would be beneficial

Comment: As a footnote, `curl` can handle multiple input URLs in a single call, so the `for` loop can likely be removed in favour of `curl -s https://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/(cat uniprot_ids.txt).fasta > uniprot_seqs.fasta`

Comment: thank you all :) will take into consideration the advice and comments given

Answer (score 0):

This might be quite silly of me, using bash command in front of what I actually want to do made this possible:

```
bash -c 'for acc in `cat meltome_protein_ids.txt` ; do curl -s "https://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/$acc.fasta"; done > uniprot_seqs.fasta'
```